# Does the Silver-Fed Salvage-o-Matic count towards the monthly salvage achievement?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The [Silver-Fed Salvage-o-Matic](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Silver-Fed_Salvage-o-Matic) recently came up for sale in the Gem Store.

Before I buy it, I'm wondering if using it counts towards the daily / monthly achievement?

I've been asking in-game but no one seems to have bought it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

As long as an item is being salvaged, it will give credit towards the salvage achievements.
The item which you use to do this doesn't matter.